# Linked list: struct for creating(?) Node?

Tags: c

I came across typedef declaration or definition(?) while learning about linked listsin c:

```
typedef struct _node{
 int a;
 struct _node* next
} node;
```

I have no idea how it can work since the above typedef declaration's body it initiates a pointer variable with its own structure(it seems like _node is being used while defining _node). Or is there anything wrong in my understanding of what it actually does? From depiction maybe I got confused over different terms as well.

Comment: The code you presented is invalid. Could be `struct _node *next;`.

Comment: No doubt this is a typo.  The supplied snippet does not even compile.

Comment: Yes I wrote it wrong I will edit my post thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, the type definition will only work after the struct is defined and not while defining it(C does only allow forward definitions).

This is why you cannot use `node` but `struct node_`.

In the code, you can use `node` because the compiler will interpret it as `struct node_`.

Comment: Thank you! I wrote it wrong( I mean the part struct* _node = next so I edited my post. Sorry for the confusion) but u said typedef only works after struct is defined so does it mean the code above can work without predefined struct for _node??